# MATLAB Edit Text: Display more than 8 characters

Tags: matlab, textbox

I'm trying to display this number '16777215' in an Edit Text in MATLAB GUI but i end up getting this number '1.67772e+07'

This is the code for displaying the number in the textbox:

```
set(handles.edit7, 'string', max_count);
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you could sue sprintf function. For example:

```
mFigure = figure()
mTextBox = uicontrol('style','text',  'Position', [20 240 200 20])

set(mTextBox,'String', sprintf('%d', 16777215))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to observe the same behaviour that you mentioned.  When I wrapped `max_count` in the function to convert the number to a string, `num2str`, 16777215 appeared as expected:

```
set(handles.edit7, 'string', num2str(max_count));
```